# How to define Android GraphView in the layout file?

Tags: android, graph

[GraphView](http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html) library for Android has a GraphView class, which is a View for creating graphs. This abstract class extends LinearLayout, so you can include a graph in layout by nesting LinearLayouts, like this:

xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/subLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />       
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GraphViewData[] data = new GraphViewData[num];
        double v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            v += 0.1;
            data[i] = new GraphViewData(i, Math.sin(v));            
        }
        GraphViewSeries seriesSin = new GraphViewSeries("Sinus", null, data);  
        GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(this, "DemoGraphView");
        graphView.addSeries(seriesSin);
        graphView.setViewPort(2, 10);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.subLayout);  
        layout.addView(graphView);        
    }
}
```

I nest LinearLayouts now but maybe there is a better way to include a graph in the layout file, eg. just like you place TextView or Button views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could remove your subLayout and add the GraphView directly to the mainLayout. So you would save one layout.

Comment: How do you do it? First you have to create your own view by extending GraphView? Is there any resource on this you could point me to?

Answer (score 1):

subLayout needs to have a fixed height for a GraphView:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/subLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="250dip"
android:orientation="vertical" />
```

see:
https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos/blob/master/res/layout/graphs.xml